# Java for loop from 0 to 0

Tags: java, android

Will any problems arise from using the following for loop when variable is equal to 0?

```
for(int i = 0; i < variable; i++)
```

This seems to sometimes work, but other times I am getting an error with the code inside the for loop. Should I be specifying to only run the for loop when variable is greater than 0? I had figured the for loop simply wouldn't run through at all if the initialization and termination values were the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if variable=0 , then the for loop will NEVER run..

Comment: Darn, that's what I thought. Unfortunately this means something else is causing the error. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: the termination field in for loop will return false so will the for loop..and `i<variable` (ie. 0<0) will ever return false and the loop terminates..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"Should I be specifying to only run the for loop when variable is greater than 0?"**

**Answer:** No. If the *termination* condition of the `for` is false, its body won't be executed.

According to [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html):

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    ...
}
```

- The *initialization* expression initializes the loop; it's executed
  once, as the loop begins.
- When the *termination* expression evaluates
  to false, the loop terminates.
- The *increment* expression is invoked
  after each iteration through the loop; it is perfectly acceptable for
  this expression to increment or decrement a value.

Answer (score 1):

> I had figured the for loop simply wouldn't run through at all if the initialization and termination values were the same.

You *had figured* correctly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int variable = 0;
  System.out.println("Before for");
  for (int i = 0; i < variable; i++) {
    System.out.printf("i = %d\n", i);
  }
  System.out.println("After for");
}
```

Outputs

```
Before for
After for
```